# Why does IronPython str() of a string object raise a UnicodeEncodeError?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, ironpython

Our web app utilizes custom made IronPython scripts (the IronPython version is 2.7.3)

An object in the script is converted to string at one point. It is definitely a string. It is provided by our app and its value has come from an outer system.
The line that raises the exception is:

```
return str(customField.Value)
```

where `customField.Value` is the object I have been describing (`customField.Value` is of type object).

The object is a string as `customField` is of type text (a type from our app) and I can pull out its value, which looks like a standard English string and has no characters out of ASCII scope.

The exception logged (after processing by our logger) is:

```
Error on uploading case data: ('unknown', '\x00', 0, 1, '')
['Equals', 'GetHashCode', 'GetType', 'InitializeFromClr', 'Item', 'MemberwiseClone',
 'ReferenceEquals', 'ToString', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__',
 '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__hash__', '__init__',
 '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__',
 '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', 'args', 'clsException',
 'encoding', 'end', 'message', 'object', 'reason', 'start']
message: --- ---
args: --- ('unknown', '\x00', 0, 1, '') ---
CLR Exception: --- System.Text.EncoderFallbackException ---
Error located in on line 531 in function 
Error located in on line 410 in function packData...
```

Why is this happening?
What should I do to resolve this exception, and what is the proper way to modify the script?

Comment: Any chance of a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character ? (That's what came up when I googled "\x00")

Comment: How can I resolve that? I do not know why would it work for many values but fail for only few and all are coming from manual input? Do you have any suggestion how to resolve this?

Comment: the source is actually manual import then the string gets pulled through c# code and gets to the IronPython

Comment: also, null is a part of ASCII scale

Answer (score 4):

Resolved:
str() applied on a str object that is an unicode string, with characters out of ascii scope, throws the exception described

a solution for me was to instead of str() use the following method:

```
def safeStringConversion(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        return obj
    else:
        return str(obj)
```

with this, unicode strings have been passed in preserved form througout the app

Comment: Hey, if you could explain why this works, that would be great, what does isinstance mean and all? BTW this function solved my many problems, so thanks alot